# Не работает часть скрипта JavaScript

Tags: jquery

Подключаю к проекту следующие файлы:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.min.js" ></script>
```

Есть ли какой-то способ, один из них работать только для одного вставленного скрипта? Если оставлять первый, то не работают клики по создающимся вкладкам:

```js
  $('#tabs a.tab').live('click', function() {
                // Get the tab name
                var bannername = $(this).attr("id") + "_banner";


                // hide all other tabs
                $("#banner > div").hide();
                $("#tabs li").removeClass("current");

                // show current tab
                $("#" + bannername).show();
                $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            });
```

Если оставлять второй, то вкладки работают, но пропадает другая часть функций.

Comment: Зачем подключаете две разные версии jQuery?

Comment: вы консоль браузера вообще просматриваете на предмет ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

В версии 3.3.1 метод live уже удалён и не будет работать. Вместо live нужно использовать on

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $('#tabs a.tab').on('click', function() {
            // Get the tab name
            var bannername = $(this).attr("id") + "_banner";


            // hide all other tabs
            $("#banner > div").hide();
            $("#tabs li").removeClass("current");

            // show current tab
            $("#" + bannername).show();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        });
```